# Boot lubuntu 20.04 into command and not gui

Tags: boot, lubuntu, 20.04, display-manager, openbox

So I have been using debian, raspbian and ubuntu, and I'm used to 'systemctl disable/enable lightdm' and 'systemctl start/stop lightdm' when I setup a server so I only use the gui when necessary. I believe now I am running openbox, but I cannot find the equivalent commands for openbox. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about a r.pi?  Some hardware specs & other details may help.   Lubuntu 20.04 on x86_64/amd64 uses `sddm` by default, and doesn't include `lightdm`. `openbox` isn't a display manager, but yes is used by Lubuntu - but it's unclear what you're trying to do with the commands (lack of detail, raspbian is for pi's but you've not said what architecture & Lubuntu doesn't offer a r.pi image so details would help)

Comment: Thanks guiverc, I see that it is indeed sddm. It looks like the commands might be the same, substituting sddm for lightdm. I'm setting up some camera servers with UdooX86 sbc, so I need to use gui to set up views and confirm camera settings, but I don't want gui running at other times.

Comment: It's best if you provide additional details in your question (*that's what the majority of people will read, not the comments, so details such as your architecture/sbc currently aren't in your question and thus will be missed by many readers*). You can edit your questions & place additional detail there.

Comment: If you're using a display manager (DM), then regardless of whether it is lightdm, gdm, xdm etc. then you should be able to set the default target to be non-graphical using `systemctl set-default multi-user.target`